# Shared access for a key accross multiple channels

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have 2 channels org1 is a member of Channel 1 and org2 is a member of channel 2 both need to access common key in dB [ Reason behind having this setup is txn done by org1 shouldn't be accessible to members of org2 and vice-versa ] 
I cannot use transient argument because I need those data when I query particular txn
How to go about it

Comment: What do you mean by DB? By default, data across channels are not shared with participants not in the channel. If you require to access data from the other channel, you can only perform operations if the participant is a member of the channel.

Comment: DB here refers to level DB or couch DB basically I am talking about states

Comment: Keys in each channel are distinct and isolated. Data in each channel would be logically disjoint from each other in couchDB using couchDB databases and encrypted. So its not possible to share a common key across channels. What is your idea behind doing this?